# How to change 1,000,000 price to 1,XXX,XXX using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, price

This is my source code:

```
preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9]/', 'X', number_format('1000000'));
```

Result: **x,xxx,xxx**

But, I want the result like **1,xxx,xxx**, i.e., don't replace the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of straightforward ways to do it in JavaScript:

```js
var input = "1,000,000"
var output = input.substr(0,1) + input.substr(1).replace(/\d/g, 'x')
console.log(output)

// or:
var output2 = input.replace(/\d/g, function(m, i) { return i ? 'x' : m })
console.log(output2)
```

(I assume you can convert at least the first one to PHP with no trouble if you'd rather do it server-side, though you did ask for PHP *or* JS.)

Comment: i would like to covert in PHP more than JS. Could you help me?

Comment: If you didn't want JS why did you include it as an option in your question? Sorry, I don't know PHP, but I'm sure it has a `substr()` function, so surely you can convert my first method to PHP? I did originally have the JS string `.slice()` method, but I've now changed it to `.substr()` (which does the same thing) to make it closer to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code when you are using PHP:

```
<?php
$number  = '1000000';
$x = number_format($number);
echo $result = str_replace("0", "X", $x);
?>
```

Comment: I would like to replace 0-9 not only 0, because my number will be 1,250,050

Comment: You can probably use `/\w/` in place of `"0"` to replace any letter or digit, upper or lower case.

Comment: Please use this:
<?php
function getValue($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    return substr($str, 0, 1).str_repeat('X', $len - 1);
}

$number  = '1250050';
echo $my = getValue($number);
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo preg_replace('/(?!^)\S/',  'X', number_format('1000000'));
```